# C++ Please can someone explain this line of code?

Tags: c++, sdk

code line: `RECOG_OBJECTS *pRecogObjects = (RECOG_OBJECTS*)pEvtInst;`

I'm currently working with an SDK while also learning advanced C++. The right hand side in particular is currently hard for me to interpret.

Comment: It's a C style type cast, telling the compiler that it should treat the right hand side as if it is of type `RECOG_OBJECTS*`.

Comment: Downvoter: I know SO rules are basically "vote whatever you feel is appropriate," but please rethink it in cases like this. People who are just starting out may not even know what they are looking at, and they are forced to ask very un-pointed questions just to get their foot in the door. If you don't know what you don't know, you can't ask the appropriate question. Don't make this person feel like they shouldn't get help.

Answer (score 1):

It is using a cast to cause the compiler to reinterpret pEvtInst as a pointer to RECOG_OBJECTS. Perhaps, at that point in the code, pEvtInst is defined as some other type of variable. Casts allow you to tell the compiler to treat variables as if they were variables of a different type.

```
int x = 0x48692100;
printf("Message: %s\n", (char*)&x);
```

In the above example, even though `x` is an integer, I have "casted" it as a `(char*)` so that it is treated as if it were a pointer to a character string instead of the integer it really is. In this specific case, if I chose the number correctly, it should print "Hi!".

Answer (score 0):

It defines `pRecogObjects` as a pointer to `RECOG_OBJECTS` and initialises that pointer to the value `(RECOG_OBJECTS*)pEvtInst`.

`(RECOG_OBJECTS*)pEvtInst` converts the value of `pEvtInst` into a pointer to `RECOG_OBJECTS`.    This is a explicit type conversion (sometimes called a typecast) from C.

The effect depends on what `pEvtInst` actually is (e.g. if it is a pointer, what does it point to).

BTW:  using explicit type conversions (aka typecasts) is often not a hallmark of advanced C++.   More often than not, advanced C++ involves using techniques in order to avoid doing such conversions.